# sklearn class_weight in random forest does the opposite of what I expect

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using the [RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) of sklearn on data with highly imbalanced classes--lots of `0` and few of `1`. I'm interested in the number of `1`s in the prediction. Example ([credit](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/handle_imbalanced_classes_in_random_forests/)):

```
# Load libraries
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
# Make class highly imbalanced by removing first 40 observations
X = X[46:,:]
y = y[46:]
# Create target vector indicating if class 0, otherwise 1
y = np.where((y == 0), 1, 0)
#split into training and testing
trainx = X[::2]
trainy = y[::2]
testx = X[1::2]
testy = y[1::2]
# Create decision tree classifer object
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
# Train model
clf.fit(trainx, trainy)
print(clf.predict(testx).sum())
```

This returns 2. Which is fine, except on my real data the result is a bit lower than the true answer. I want to deal with this by using the `class_weight` parameter. However when I do:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight="balanced") 
# Train model
clf.fit(trainx, trainy)
print(clf.predict(testx).sum())
```

I get a result of 0. Same if I use `class_weight={1:10}`. If I use `class_weight={1:.1}` I get 2 again.

I get similar behavior on my real data: the higher the weight I give to class `1`, the fewer `1`s I get in the prediction.

This is the opposite of the behavior I expect (and the opposite of what the `class_weight` parameter does in [svm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html)). What's going on here? [This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26325/class-weight-ineffective-in-sklearn) suggests sklearn is assigning the class labels by some kind of default, but that seems bizarre. Why wouldn't it use the class labels I gave it?

Comment: Try this: from collections import Counter; class_weight=Counter(trainy). 'balanced' option seemed always strange for me.

Comment: @avchauzov yup that gives me the result would expect from class_weight='balanced'. Seems like this parameter is inverted, which I would think is a bug the devs would want to fix. Anyway if you post this an as answer I'll accept

Comment: @andbeonetraveler By the way, there are special [imbalanced-learn package](https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/install.html) for imbalanced data sets. May be worth checking.